# Issue replacing the default WelcomeDlg dialog

Tags: wix

I have managed to add a custom dialog in the middle of the sequence which collects several values from the user and saves them to the registry (in the dialog with ID `ApiKeyDlg`).

However, I'm having difficulty (5+ hours wasted) replacing the WelcomeDlg with a custom dialog during major upgrades only. I.E. I want to show a custom WelcomeDlg that goes straight to the VerifyReadyDlg for Major Upgrades (detected using `Installed OR PREVFOUND`).

I have also tried using `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`, same results.

What am I doing incorrectly here? Is it my condition that is failing or am I misunderstanding the process of editing the sequence?

`Light.exe` shows no errors, but it fails to either:

1. Detect that an older version of the app is already installed
2. Show the `UpgradeWelcomeDlg` after detecting an old version installed

I'm not sure how I can narrow down which part is failing?

```
<UI>
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

    <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />

    <DialogRef Id="DiskCostDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="LicenseAgreementDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="VerifyReadyDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
    <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
    <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
    <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

    <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">NOT Installed OR NOT PREVFOUND</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="UpgradeWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed OR PREVFOUND</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ApiKeyDlg">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="ApiKeyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="ApiKeyDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg"></Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="ApiKeyDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="UpgradeWelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed OR PREVFOUND</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>


    <Dialog Id="ApiKeyDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup">

        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.ProgressDlgBannerBitmap)" />
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" />
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Only the Organisation ID is required unless you're using a web proxy" />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Agent configuration" />

        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />

        <Control Id="ApiKeyLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="55" Width="290" Height="10" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Organisation ID (required):" />
        <Control Id="ApiKey" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="70" Width="300" Height="18" Property="UI_ORGANISATION" Indirect="yes" />

        <Control Id="ProxyAddressLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="95" Width="290" Height="10" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Proxy server address (optional):" />
        <Control Id="Proxy" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="110" Width="300" Height="18" Property="UI_PROXYADDRESS" Indirect="yes" />

        <Control Id="ProxyUsernameLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="130" Width="290" Height="10" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Proxy username (leave blank for default):" />
        <Control Id="ProxyUsername" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="145" Width="300" Height="18" Property="UI_PROXYUSERNAME" Indirect="yes" />

        <Control Id="ProxyPasswordLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="165" Width="290" Height="10" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Proxy password (leave blank for default):" />
        <Control Id="ProxyPassword" Type="Edit" Password="yes" X="20" Y="180" Width="300" Height="18" Property="UI_PROXYPASSWORD" Indirect="yes" />

        <Control Id="ScoutCheckbox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="205" Width="300" Height="17" Property='SCOUTSHORTCUT' CheckBoxValue='1'>
            <Text> Create a Start Menu shortcut for SomeApplicationName Scout (optional)</Text>
        </Control>
    </Dialog>

    <Dialog Id="UpgradeWelcomeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Update">
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" >
            <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="Update">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgBitmap)" />
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="135" Y="80" Width="220" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgDescription)" >
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="135" Y="20" Width="220" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgTitle)" />
    </Dialog>
    <InstallUISequence>
        <Show Dialog="UpgradeWelcomeDlg" Before="ProgressDlg">Installed OR PREVFOUND</Show>
    </InstallUISequence>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
</UI>
```

Ultimately, I want to show completely different dialogs for Major Upgrades compared to an initial install.

Answer (score 0):

Well then... I just managed to get it working using this:

```
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">NOT Installed OR NOT PREVFOUND OR NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="UpgradeWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed OR PREVFOUND OR WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Publish>
```

Perhaps writing this question cleared my mind! Who knows.